# Appropriate WP hook to use set PHP cookie

Tags: hooks, cookies

I'm trying to set cookie in `init` hook.

```
add_action( 'init', 'sa_maybe_set_cookie' );

function sa_maybe_set_cookie() {
   

   if ( ! empty( get_option( 'sa_allow_cookie' ) ) {
       setcookie( 'sa-cookie', $cookie, time() + ( 86400 * 30 ), "/" );
   }
}
```

but it looks like header is already sent on `init` and so got an error message in the log

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\laragon\www\dev\wp-cron.php:30) in C:\laragon\www\dev\wp-content\plugins\sa-geo\src\Plugin.php on line 34
```

line 34 is the `setcookie()` ^^ above.

lookng into wp-cron.php's line 29-31, it has:

```
} elseif ( function_exists( 'litespeed_finish_request' ) ) {
    litespeed_finish_request();
}
```

Is `wp` a better hook than `init` or any priority will help?

Comment: Have you tried `wp`?